# jQuery run a function every 5 seconds in a jsp page

Tags: jquery

I have a following script in my jsp page that I need to refresh (call) every 5 seconds to refresh the data to be displayed:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

            var sampleData = <%=sms.getTimeline()%>;

            ...
        });
```

Can someone please let me know how to do so?

Thanks,

Comment: You can't really mix JavaScript and a server side language

Comment: You've got to be joking. RTFD. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setInterval

Comment: Well I can, I get the result from server side. I only need to refresh the result every 5 sec.

Answer (score 2):

You can use setInterval to run your javascript code or function after each specific interval

**[HELP](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)**